# CSS JS and HTML Modal over the page Window trigger with Button and Link

Tags: css, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I would like to be able to use a link ( instead of a button)  to trigger a modal window.
In fact I would like to use either one in the same code base ...
Thee Button works but the link: "Open Modal in Link" doezs not..

Added the link with the id  as per other suggestions but does not work

Any help would be appreciateed!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Modal with Header and Footer</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<a href="#" id="myBtn">Open Modal in Link</a>




<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

sample: https://devtest253.w3spaces.com/test2.html

Comment: Is that really how you have it? You have too many closing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because you have the same ID on both the button and the link. So when you are selecting that ID in JavaScript, its just grabbing the first one which is the button.

Comment: Thanks Steve-- You are absolutely correct!   If I use a different ID pointing at the same modal the link works but the the button does not -- 
Changes made: 
1) Modified call out in href to unique id:
        <a href="#" id="myBtn1">Open Modal in Link</a>
In script section added: 
           var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

Is there a way to have them both pointing to the same Modal?

Comment: There is probably a more elegant way, but you could always just add another function identical to the btn one, but with a new variable created for the link ID. So you would have btn = document.getElementById("myBtn") and then link = document.getElementById("myBtn1") and then you would have a second function to activate the modal link.onClick = function {} etc

Comment: Yeah -- did that to test it -- and it is ugly but works -- MANY THANKS for your help!

Comment: No problem, otherwise you could try out using document.querySelectorAll and selecting a class that the modal and link both have. Then you would use something like a forEach() loop to execute the function. Don't forget to mark the question as answered if you are all set ;)